# Querying a json file from a url string (php)

Tags: php, json, data.gov

I'm trying to use the data.gov.uk to grab the court data and do cool stuff with it. Problem I am having is if I try to decode the version from the server in php: https://courttribunalfinder.service.gov.uk/api.html it just won't load. It only works if I download the courts.json file and decode from that. However then I'm unable to query the data with something like courts.json?q=bristol say.

So my question is, should I be able to decode directly from the gov website or do I need to do it locally, and if that's the case how would I allow me to feed query strings to my local json file?

e.g. I want to be able to do something like:

```
$jsonurl = directory() . '/courts.json?q=old+bailey';
$json =   wp_remote_get($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$court = json_decode($json['body'], true);
```

Answer (score 0):

well, 
There are two options for you

1) Use `cURL Library` as mentioned by  Joanvo

2) use `YQL(Yahoo Query Language)` that is also another powerful thing around.